# For each out of bounds because of changes to the List while running

Tags: java

There is a base class that contains a subclass as a member.
in said subclass, I've got a method where there is a for each loop where I run over a list and run a method on each of the vars in the said list.
In said list there are two objects that may or may not remove objects from the base class's list.
Problem is for some reason the loop crashes whenever said two objects remove an element from the list. Interesting thing is for some reason only if the second object removes an element from the list the program crashes. I've tried adding more variables like this and for some reason only the second to last object can remove elements from the list without having the program crash.
Would love some help on the matter. added some base code:

```
public class Game {
private SpriteCollection sprites;
public void initialize() {
    sprites.addelement(e1);
    sprites.addelement(e2);
    sprites.addelement(remover removerElement1);
    sprites.addelement(remover removerElement2);
    }
public class spriteCollection {
public java.util.List<Sprite> sprites;
    public void notifyAllTimePassed() {
            for (Sprite c : sprites) {  // for each sprite
                c.timePassed(); // move it
            }
        }
    }
public class remover {
public void timePassed() {
removesprite(e1, game) // removing the element from the game which 
 // contains the sprite collection the remover element is a part of
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a subclass in your question, but in any case - you are not allowed to change a list while iterating over it. That will cause a `ConcurrentModificationException`. If you want to remove elements you have to do it with the iterator, and not use a `for` loop.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Point taken, that actually solved most of my trouble, thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

I found a rather convenient solution while trying to debug the thing.
Instead of working with a for each loop, I, instead, choose to use iterators, and found it far simpler. all that was needed was the:

```
for (Sprite c : sprites) {  // for each sprite
            c.timePassed(); // move it
        }
```

with a

```
for (int i = 0; i < sprites.size(); i++) {
        Sprite tempSprite = sprites.get(i);
        tempSprite.timePassed();
    }
```

so that if the size decreases, the whole thing would immediately stop thus, not running an empty index.
Solution is rather banal, surprised I've been stuck at this for so long honestly.

Comment: That's not actually using an iterator. You're using indexes. This runs the risk that if you remove an element, you'll be skipping indices.